# Php Time Math With Fractional Seconds

Tags: php

I need to do time math with fractional seconds in a php script. For example I will have an initial time and need to add 0.234 seconds to it. The Date Add utilities all do math using integer seconds so will not work in this case.

Currently I am taking my initial time, breaking it up into hours, minutes, seconds, then adding my adjustment to the seconds, finding out if I spilled over 60, etc, and putting everything back together. I am making a lot of assumptions (like my hour won't roll over, etc) and there has to be a better way.

Comment: most of php's date/time functions only handle seconds as an integer. you can get fractional seconds from some things, like `microtime(true)`, but there's very little way to actually deal with the fractional part with the existing infrastructure - the input functions expect ints, meaning PHP will typecast your float value to integer.

Comment: DateTime throws an exception if you try to say "10:12:67.23". So that puts me back at handling all the rollovers manually.